# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). AGAIN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, python3, pip

I realize this seems to be a very popular question but none of the fixes worked for me. I use ubuntu 18.04 and I've been unable to `apt install` anything for the good part of 6 months. It says the issue is coming from `python3-pip` which I am unable to use too. I tried purging it but I get a similar traceback.

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone who has an idea how to fix this. It seems to have broken `apt` itself

Comment: Please edit your answer with the things you tried. We can't help you, if just say 'it does not work'

Answer (score 1):

Here's first three results when I googled that:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2416238

https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error/

Do any of these help you?

Answer (score 1):

The message itself indicates what you should do.  You should run `sudo apt install python3-pip` to attempt to install the package again.  If APT refuses, simply run `apt download python3-pip`, then run `sudo dpkg -i python3-pip*.deb`.  That should install the package and ensure it's in a good state.

If you still have a dependency problem, try `sudo apt -f install` to make sure the dependencies are correct and install the appropriate packages.  If you then want to remove the `python3-pip` package, you can do so, once APT is in a good state.

Comment: nothing works. I get the same error everytime.